# How to remove from a List when total values by date net to zero

Tags: c#, list

I have a C# List of transactions

```
public class Transaction
{
        public string effectiveDate;
        public string transactionType;
        public double grossAmount;
        public double netAmount;
}
```

Different transactionTypes are stored in different lists which are populated pulling data from database.
At the end it spits out a statement of itemised transactions.

Lets say I have a monthly admin fee $1.50 paid on 15th of the month. In February the fee is waived, and I have a reversal transaction. So now in my list I have

```
'2020-01-15', 'Admin fee', 1.5, 1.5
'2020-02-15', 'Admin fee', 1.5, 1.5
'2020-02-15', 'Admin fee', -1.5, -1.5
'2020-03-15', 'Admin fee', 1.5, 1.5
```

How can I remove or skip the Feb admin fees if they nett out to zero?

In other instances I might have 10 or more transactions of the same type on the same day that get reversed, ie 10 payments received and reversed with same effective date.

Is sorting by date, iterating and keeping running total of values until I get to a new date then comparing to zero the easiest/nicest way?

I know this would be easier to do in the SQL with group by having sum <> 0, but the values are stored in database as chars with $ and comma and leading trailing whitespace etc so I cant go that way. For various reasons, not even if I replace/replace/replace/convert the data.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: why keep `effectiveDate` as `string`? Since it is some date, `DateTime effectiveDate` will be more natural

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your attempt(s)  to see how did you try to tackle the problem.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Fair Q. Each year an annual statement job runs, pulling relevant data from many tables and putting into one transaction table. Historically no operations are done on this table so they just stored everything as strings. This table was then read and pumped into a plain text file. That is why it has all the formatting and spacing.  Then a vb app was written to create csv files. I guess thats when the formatting started getting stripped out. Then I came along and converted to C# xml output. It was a MyFirstC# job a few years back. There would be plenty of room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *Linq*, for given list, say

```
  var myList = new List<Transaction>() {
    new Transaction() {
      effectiveDate = "2020-01-15",
      transactionType = "Admin fee",
      grossAmount = 1.5,
      netAmount = 1.5},

    new Transaction() {
      effectiveDate = "2020-02-15",
      transactionType = "Admin fee",
      grossAmount = 1.5,
      netAmount = 1.5},

    new Transaction() {
      effectiveDate = "2020-02-15",
      transactionType = "Admin fee",
      grossAmount = -1.5,
      netAmount = -1.5},

    new Transaction() {
      effectiveDate = "2020-03-15",
      transactionType = "Admin fee",
      grossAmount = 1.5,
      netAmount = 1.5},
  };
```

You can put Linq query:

1. We `GroupBy` transactions with the same `effectiveDate` and `transactionType`
2. Check if `Sum` of `netAmount` is not 0
3. Flatten (`SelectMany` followed by `ToList`) groups back to list

Code:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  myList = myList
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.effectiveDate, t.transactionType })
    .Where(group => group.Sum(t => t.netAmount) != 0)
    .SelectMany(group => group)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome. Had trouble to start because of the precision of double. The sum of the transactions was "not quite" zero so they still appeared. Fixed with `.Where(group => Math.Round(group.Sum(t => t.netAmount),2) != 0)` But this now brings up whole new lot of enhancements that can be made. I currently have 43 different lists of transactions. Every time a new transaction is created I have to create a new list and new code to output that list. Using Linq I could have just one List and handle it completely differently. Although that is a bigger change that I may not be allowed. Thanks! (I think) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could use LinQ to group your results by day and type and then calculate the sum of the grouped elements. When sum==0 skip...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Transaction> transactions;
var noUnderZeroFees = transactions.Where(x => x.netAmount > 0).ToList<Transaction>();
//noUnderZeroFees will contains Transaction items with more then Zero netAmount.
```

Try to search more about LINQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
List<Transaction> loList = new List<Transaction>();
loList.Add(new Transaction()
{
    effectiveDate = "2020-01-15",
    transactionType = "Admin fee",
    grossAmount = 1.5,
    netAmount = 1.5
});
loList.Add(new Transaction()
{
    effectiveDate = "2020-02-15",
    transactionType = "Admin fee",
    grossAmount = 1.5,
    netAmount = 1.5
});
loList.Add(new Transaction()
{
    effectiveDate = "2020-02-15",
    transactionType = "Admin fee",
    grossAmount = -1.5,
    netAmount = -1.5
});
loList.Add(new Transaction()
{
    effectiveDate = "2020-03-15",
    transactionType = "Admin fee",
    grossAmount = 1.5,
    netAmount = 1.5
});

foreach (var loGTrans in loList.GroupBy(item => new { item.transactionType, item.effectiveDate }).Where(item => item.Sum(t => t.netAmount) != 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Type: {loGTrans.Key.transactionType}, Date: {loGTrans.Key.effectiveDate} -> Gross-Sum: ${loGTrans.Sum(item => item.grossAmount)} Net-Sum:${loGTrans.Sum(item => item.netAmount)}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first `GroupBy()` transactionType and then you calculate the `Sum()` of netAmount foreach group. With the `Where()`-statement you include only the groups that fit the filter and then you dissolve the groups with `SelectMany()`

```
    private IEnumerable<Transaction> FilterNetZero(IEnumerable<Transaction> list)
    {
        return list.GroupBy(s => s.transactionType)
                   .Where(group => group.Sum(s => s.netAmount) != 0)
                   .SelectMany(group => group);
    }
```